# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError JNI error

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to use Java native Interface.

I created a shared library object .so file by using these commands

```
ln -s /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_21/include /usr/include/JNILibForProj
gcc -I /usr/include/JNILibForProj -c -Wall -w -fpic CppCode.cpp
gcc -shared -o libCppCode.so CppCode.o
```

I placed the .so file in /usr/lib
I load the other library files from there.

However when I attempt to load the library using

```
System.loadLibrary("CppCode");
```

I get error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/libCppCode.so: /usr/lib/libCppCode.so: undefined symbol: _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
```

Other .so files in the same location load properly. So the location of the file is not the problem. I also tried compiling with g++ but I am getting the same error message.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit**
Actually I have written some opencv code in CPP and i am trying to link through JNI. I am using this line for creating the .so file now. I am not ood at g++ can you please check whether what I have written is correct???

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_21/include -I/usr/include/JNILibForProj -L/usr/local/lib -O0 -g3 -Wall -w -c -fpic -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o "/home/shikhar/Desktop/myLib/libCppCode.so" "../src/CppCode.cpp" -lopencv_core -lpHash -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lstdc++
```

After creating .so and copying it to /usr/lib
The previous error message has gone but now I am getting

> only ET_DYN and ET_EXEC can be loaded

**Edit 2**
After a lot of hit and trial I have figured out the solution. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The missing symbol belongs to the Standard C++ library. So you have to ensure that the Standard C++ library is properly linked to your shared library.

Mostly, you can achieve it by adding `-lstdc++` to linker line:

```
gcc -shared -o libCppCode.so -lstdc++ CppCode.o
```

Answer (score 0):

The final command which created the .so file correctly is

```
g++ -shared "../src/JavaCPPInterfaceFaceRecognition.cpp" -o "/home/shikhar/Desktop/myLib/libJavaCPPInterfaceFaceRecognition.so" -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_21/include -I/usr/include/JNILibForProj -L/usr/local/lib -O0 -g3 -Wall -w -fpic -lopencv_core -lpHash -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lstdc++
```

In the first edit, the command I mentioned had an error that it conatined-c because of which it was ignoring the linking step
Source: http://www.think-techie.com/2009/08/java-native-interface-jni.html